# Consuming Svelte store data in functions

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Yes Im dumb. Coming from 6 years of React dev and building my first app with Svelte. The tutorial was fun but now im trying to actually just build and I'm confused with how a store works. I can't seem to google the right question and AI has not been helpful in the slightest. I've read the docs and am clearly missing something.

I have a user store which checks firebase and returns the user. (code below) and I want to consume the user data and pass its values with an API call. However the router keeps breaking when I try to use $user or unsubscribe in the call. The only way I've gotten it to work to avoid $ and skip the unsubscribe method and I have a feeling I'm missing the whole point.

Works, but it seems like weird logic to have to subscribe just to read the value.

```
import { user } from "$lib/firebase";
let userData;
user.subscribe((_userData) => {
userData = _userData;
});
```

2. Breaks the router? (wtf? only error "stop is not a function"). (I thought this was supposed to be how it worked)

```
import { user } from "$lib/firebase";
myFunc({user: $user})
```

3. Attempt to unsubscribe from working method (#1) and it breaks the router again ("stop is not a function")

```
let userData;
const unsubscribe = user.subscribe((_userData) => {
userData = _userData;
});
onDestroy(() => {
unsubscribe();
} );
```

```
//firebase.js

function userStore() {
let unsubscribe;
if (!auth || !globalThis.window) {
console.warn("Auth is not initialized or not in browser");
const { subscribe } = writable(null);
return {
subscribe,
};
}
const { subscribe } = writable(auth?.currentUser ?? null, async (set) => {
unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
if (user) {
// Grab the user document from firestore
const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
const userDocSnap = await getDoc(userDocRef);
const userData = userDocSnap.data();
set(userData);
} else {
set(null);
}
});
return () => {
if (unsubscribe) {
unsubscribe();
}
};
});
return {
subscribe,
};
}
export const user = userStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is weird, but it is the way to go.  However, Svelte provides a convenient function named `get()` that does this for you.

```js
// This works in JS modules.
import { get } from 'svelte';
import { myStore } from 'wherever';

const storeValue = get(myStore);
// Now storeValue contains the value inside the store.
```